# How to access router when connected to modem?

Tags: networking, router

I'm trying to change the settings of my router, but I'm connected directly to my modem. Without changing my connection, is it possible to access this? I've tried going to `10.1.1.2` and so on, none have worked. Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: the reason people are voting down your question is because you haven't provided enough info on how things are connected, and which devices have what IP address(es) and subnet masks.  I've just provided an answer for a typical use scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that you have

- modem/router performing firewall and NAT with at least 4 LAN ports with at least the following plugged in to those LAN ports

  - your pc
  - "router" WAN port with its LAN ports filled with

    - other device 1
    - other device 2
    - other device etc..

## Easy Way

The simplest solution would be to plug your pc in the one of the LAN ports on the router, and let your PC have an IP on the router's LAN subnet then your pc could access both the LAN IP's of the router and modem/router without any trouble or fancy config.

## Hard Way

However if you insist on doing it the hard way.  As an example lets say

- your modem's LAN side IP is 10.1.1.1 and works on subnet with mask 255.255.255.0
- you PC's IP is 10.1.1.20
- the WAN side IP of your router is 10.1.1.2
- the LAN side IP of your router is 192.168.0.1 with subnet mask 255.255.255.0

There are 2 types of methods that spring to mind that you can employ, however most will require that you at least temporarily use the easy method above to set them up.

### Method 1: Remote to Behind the Router

If you have a machine connected to the LAN side of the router you can remote in to that machine and control the router from its LAN side IP address from the machine within its LAN.  This can be with something like remote desktop or a VPN server.  These are the method we use at work to access the web config portals of the modems we have at our remote branches.

Both VPN and MS remote desktop will require that you have already set this up through the router config for port forwarding.

If this is a remote branch that you just can't get to physically and the staff at the remote site cannot or should not be guided through changing the settings on the router, then email someone there a link to install something like http://www.logmein.com so you can take control of their PC, which is connected to the router LAN side, even through the firewall and NAT on both the modem and router without doing port forwarding on either.  Note that with Logmein it is best for you to setup an account first and then use the features from within the Logmein portal to generate a link that will automatically sign up their computer to the account you created.

### Method 2: Enable Router's WAN side Admin

You can go in to the router's config (using the easy method above) and change the setting to allow the WAN side access to the web admin portal.

Comment: I'm torn between upvoting you for the thorough answer, and downvoting you for encouraging such garbage questions. =)

Comment: Thanks. I realise the question is lacking, but I'm still in my 'do anything for rep' phase, and I'm pretty sure most people who search for that question will be setup like I have described.

Comment: Yes, we all went through the rep scavenging phase. Some of us never left it. =)